# Outlook 2010 plugin

Tags: xml, winforms, outlook-addin

Outlook 2010 - How to create a Right-Click Context Menu item for access within a message

The user should also be able to right click on the email body (without selecting text) -> right click and Parse Mail(Context Menu Button) (essentially parsing the entire email for c# code to extract data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) is used for customizing context menus in Outlook 2010 and later. See [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

Unfotunately not all context menus can be customized by third-party developers. Microsoft simply don't share required idMso values. You can find all publicly available idMso values in the following documents:

- [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)
- [Microsoft Office Document: [MS-CUSTOMUI2] Supporting Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=727)

Comment: I didn't find the idMso value for creating item in context menu within the mail message body when we right click in the message body.
I also follow the [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) but didn't get any success.
There is no option to creating context menu item in email message body.

Comment: Yes, nobody knows this idMso value. Unfotunately not all context menus can be customized by third-party developers.

Comment: Is there any other way to implement this functionality?

Comment: There is no trivial way to get the job done until you know the required idMso value. Consider adding your custom controls to the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old topic, I was struggling with a similar thing and it took me forever to find it.  The idMso value for the context menu in the body of an email is ContextMenuReadOnlyMailText.  Using Fluent UI it will allow you to add a new item to the right click contextual menu inside the email body.